# JScript Enumerator and list of properties

Tags: jscript, wsh

Consider the following WSH snippet:

```
var query = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Printer", "WQL", 0);
var e = new Enumerator(query);
for ( ; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext ()) { 
    var p = e.item();
    WScript.Echo(p.Name + " (" + p.Status + ")");
}
```

It prints in every line a printer name and the word "undefined" in brackets (because `Status` property isn't exist in `p` object). The question is: how can I list all available properties from `p`? The usual technique with `for (var i in p) {...}` doesn't work--it seems that properties in `p` object aren't enumerable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JScript's `for...in` statement isn't compatible with WMI objects, because, well, they are more complex than native JScript objects. WMI objects expose their property collection via the special [`Properties_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393781(VS.85).aspx) property, so to list all available properties of an object, you need to enumerate this collection like you enumerate the query results to access individual WMI objects. Each object property is represented by a [`SWbemProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393804(VS.85).aspx) object that has the `Name`, `Value` and other properties providing info about the appropriate object property.

This example should help you get the idea:

```
var query = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT Name, Status FROM Win32_Printer");
var colPrinters = new Enumerator(query);

var oPrinter, colProps, p;

// Enumerate WMI objects
for ( ; !colPrinters.atEnd(); colPrinters.moveNext()) { 
    oPrinter = colPrinters.item();

    // Enumerate WMI object properties
    colProps = new Enumerator(oPrinter.Properties_);
    for ( ; !colProps.atEnd(); colProps.moveNext()) { 
        p = colProps.item();
        WScript.Echo(p.Name + ": " + p.Value);
    }
}
```

Note that this script will also display the `DeviceID` property value, because it's a key property of the `Win32_Printer` class, so it's also retrieved in order to uniquely identify class instances.

Comment: @HenryFlower As much as I like those cyrillic letters it's best to write in English here :) By the way, I wouldn't think a "Henry Flower" would be from Russia!

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to avoid the need to use an explicit Enumerator every time you need to iterate over a collection object that needs one, you can define a little helper function like this:

```
function forEach(collection, func) {
 for (var e = new Enumerator(collection); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
  func(e.item());
 }
}
```

Iteration over collections then becomes rather less clumsy:

```
var queryResult = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT Name, Status FROM Win32_Printer");

// Enumerate WMI objects
forEach (queryResult, function (oPrinter) {

    // Enumerate WMI object properties
    forEach (oPrinter.Properties_, function (p) {
        WScript.Echo(p.Name + ": " + p.Value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Since you can't directly `break` out of the loop from within the callback function, it might be a good idea to include a return value condition check in the loop, such as `if(func(e.item()) === false) break;`, allowing you to `return false` from within the callback when you need to break out

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your query you're only asking for the Name. Try asking for both Name and status:

```
var query = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT Name, Status  FROM Win32_Printer", "WQL", 0);
var e = new Enumerator(query);
for ( ; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext ()) { 
    var p = e.item();
    WScript.Echo(p.Name + " (" + p.Status + ")" );
}
```

I got some more properties from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(VS.85).aspx and several work. I queried for DriverName and Comment and both had text or at least a null.

```
var query = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT Name, Status, DriverName, Comment  FROM Win32_Printer", "WQL", 0);
var e = new Enumerator(query);
for ( ; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext ()) { 
    var p = e.item();
    WScript.Echo(p.Name + " (" + p.Status + ") " + p.DriverName + " " + p.Comment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is not in the query :) Regardless of the SELECT statement, properties of p object isn't discoverable (with "for") and this is ridiculous :(

Comment: "Yeah, I tried SELECT * from FROM Win32_Printer" and then doing for (i in p) and printing i and p.i and got nothing. But the link I posted does have all the attributes you could want, so maybe just put those in an array to get them out. All the ones I tested were there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(VS.85).aspx