# Capturing computer event using java script

Tags: events

I have a web page opened in my browser , What i want is if i open another application like paint . A alert will be displayed in the browser.
  I simply want to capture the shifting between the browser and application.
  I want the proper event description .
  My browser should always be running in first place .
  Even when auto "screen saver" or "sleep" happens I want the system event to be captured.
  I have to do this using Java script only .
  Please let me know in case of any suggestions.

Comment: Here is a link from where to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973016/jscript-enumerator-and-list-of-properties

Comment: Thanks for the information , could you please elaborate it .Or try to give any other example in which computer system events are being captured.

Comment: It involves more work than I have right now, but if you search the internet for "javascript" and "wmi" you will get tons of sources